# Nested Object Iteration with conditional statements ReactJs

Tags: javascript, java, json, reactjs, api

I have the below api call from React Js. It is a class component. am new to React Js.

```
class UserComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state=({
    users: []
});
    retrieve(e){
          e.preventDefault();
           fetch(`http://localhost:8080/test/{this.state.id}`,{
             "method":"GET",
             "headers":{
                "accept":"application/json"
               }
          })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
             users:response
          })
       }

    render(){
   return (
   <div>
   <form>
<table>
  <tbody>
  {
    this.state.users === '' || null ? '' : Object.entries(this.state.users).map([key,value])=>(
        Object.entries(key).map(field=>(
      <tr>
        <td>
         <input name = "firstName" id = firstName" defaultValue = {field.firstName} required/>
        </td>
      </tr>
))))
}
  </tbody>
</table>

</form>
</div>
)
}
}
export default UserComponent
```

I need to get the firstName and lastName and other details from a simple json file

```
{
   "id":"12224343",
    "depId":"1",
    "employees":[{
      "empId":"1",
      "firstName":"sample",
      "lastName":"test",
       "address":[{
             "street":"1",
             "pin":"12345"
    }]
    }]

}
```

I need to get the firstname and last name of this nested object and address's object's value also. Is there any way like flatmap kind of thing is available in react class component. I didn't use useEffects and all.

when I tried to iterate it am getting "map is not a function. it is undefined"

the class component with state objects have any restrictions. tried a lot of options.

I need to iterate the object of object and fetch only particular values in the UI test box. like first name and lastname. now it is iterating all and displaying all in the UI. which looks messy.

Please help me to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you initialized state users as an array. You can just use users.map(item). Each item contains multiple employees. You can also convert data from the current json file to any data structure which is comfortable for you to display in the table.

```
const {users} = this.state
    users?.map((user,index) => {
      return (
          <div key={key.id}>
            {user?.employees.map(item => {
              return (
                  <div key={item.empId + key.id}>
                    <input defaultValue = {item.firstName} required/>
                  </div>
              )
            })}
          </div>
      )
    } )
```

I suggest to choose open source UI library such as Material UI or Antd to display data inside table. It saves time to manage responsive web page styles.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. may I know is there any way to convert the nested object as a single object as we are doing in java 8 with the flatmap conversion. so that I can directly pick the values easily

Comment: Probably you need to write the converting method on your own. The object may be different in different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I have initialized an empty return object that fixes all the problems and it worked like a charm. please check the below details.

```
class UserComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state=({
    users : [{
   "id":"",
    "depId":"",
    "employees":[{
      "empId":"",
      "firstName":"",
      "lastName":"",
       "address":[{
             "street":"",
             "pin":""
    }]
    }]

}]
});
    retrieve(e){
          e.preventDefault();
           fetch(`http://localhost:8080/test/{this.state.id}`,{
             "method":"GET",
             "headers":{
                "accept":"application/json"
               }
          })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
             users:response
          })
       }

    render(){
   return (
   <div>
   <form>
<table>
  <tbody>
  {
    this.state.users === '' || null ? '' : Object.entries(this.state.users).map([key,value])=>(
        Object.entries(key).map(field=>(
      <tr>
        <td>
         <input name = "firstName" id = firstName" defaultValue = {field.firstName} required/>
        </td>
      </tr>
))))
}
  </tbody>
</table>

</form>
</div>
)
}
}
export default UserComponent
```